# Dataflow job: Failed to copy Column partitioned table to Column partitioned meta table: not supported

Tags: google-bigquery

I have an Apache Beam project that uses the Google Dataflow runner to process quite some data stored in BigQuery. The flow reads 1 main table and uses 3 different side streams. For every row in the input data set, we calculate a 'label', which generates 5 different output streams. The main BigQuery table we read is 60GB, the 3 side streams are 2GB, 51GB and 110GB each. These are all converted to a `PCollectionView<Map<String, Iterable<TableRow>>>`

Eventually, these 5 streams are combined and written back to BigQuery.

When I run this job on a subset of the data (1 million rows), the job works as expected, but when I run it on the full data set (177 million rows), the job returns the following error: **Failed to copy Column partitioned table to Column partitioned meta table: not supported**

What does this error mean? And how can I fix this? Thanks!

Full stack trace:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to create copy job with id prefix beam_load_poisrschellenberger0810134033c63e44ed_e7cf725c5321409b96a4f20e7ec234bc_3d9288a5ff3a24b9eb8b1ec9c621e7dc_00000, reached max retries: 3, last failed copy job: {
  "configuration" : {
    "copy" : {
      "createDisposition" : "CREATE_IF_NEEDED",
      "destinationTable" : {
        "datasetId" : "KPI",
        "projectId" : "bolcom-stg-kpi-logistics-f6c",
        "tableId" : "some_table_v1$20180811"
      },
      "sourceTables" : [ {
        "datasetId" : "KPI",
        "projectId" : "bolcom-stg-kpi-logistics-f6c",
        "tableId" : "beam_load_poisrschellenberger0810134033c63e44ed_e7cf725c5321409b96a4f20e7ec234bc_3d9288a5ff3a24b9eb8b1ec9c621e7dc_00002_00000"
      }, {
        "datasetId" : "KPI",
        "projectId" : "bolcom-stg-kpi-logistics-f6c",
        "tableId" : "beam_load_poisrschellenberger0810134033c63e44ed_e7cf725c5321409b96a4f20e7ec234bc_3d9288a5ff3a24b9eb8b1ec9c621e7dc_00001_00000"
      }, {
        "datasetId" : "KPI",
        "projectId" : "bolcom-stg-kpi-logistics-f6c",
        "tableId" : "beam_load_poisrschellenberger0810134033c63e44ed_e7cf725c5321409b96a4f20e7ec234bc_3d9288a5ff3a24b9eb8b1ec9c621e7dc_00004_00000"
      }, {
        "datasetId" : "KPI",
        "projectId" : "bolcom-stg-kpi-logistics-f6c",
        "tableId" : "beam_load_poisrschellenberger0810134033c63e44ed_e7cf725c5321409b96a4f20e7ec234bc_3d9288a5ff3a24b9eb8b1ec9c621e7dc_00003_00000"
      } ],
      "writeDisposition" : "WRITE_APPEND"
    }
  },
  "etag" : "\"HbYIGVDrlNbv2nDGLHCFlwJG0rI/oNgxlMGidSDy59VClvLIlEu08aU\"",
  "id" : "bolcom-stg-kpi-logistics-f6c:EU.beam_load_poisrschellenberger0810134033c63e44ed_e7cf725c5321409b96a4f20e7ec234bc_3d9288a5ff3a24b9eb8b1ec9c621e7dc_00000-2",
  "jobReference" : {
    "jobId" : "beam_load_poisrschellenberger0810134033c63e44ed_e7cf725c5321409b96a4f20e7ec234bc_3d9288a5ff3a24b9eb8b1ec9c621e7dc_00000-2",
    "location" : "EU",
    "projectId" : "bolcom-stg-kpi-logistics-f6c"
  },
  "kind" : "bigquery#job",
  "selfLink" : "https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/bolcom-stg-kpi-logistics-f6c/jobs/beam_load_poisrschellenberger0810134033c63e44ed_e7cf725c5321409b96a4f20e7ec234bc_3d9288a5ff3a24b9eb8b1ec9c621e7dc_00000-2?location=EU",
  "statistics" : {
    "creationTime" : "1533957446953",
    "endTime" : "1533957447111",
    "startTime" : "1533957447111"
  },
  "status" : {
    "errorResult" : {
      "message" : "Failed to copy Column partitioned table to Column partitioned meta table: not supported.",
      "reason" : "invalid"
    },
    "errors" : [ {
      "message" : "Failed to copy Column partitioned table to Column partitioned meta table: not supported.",
      "reason" : "invalid"
    } ],
    "state" : "DONE"
  },
  "user_email" : "595758839781-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com"
}.
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.WriteRename.copy(WriteRename.java:166)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.WriteRename.writeRename(WriteRename.java:107)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.WriteRename.processElement(WriteRename.java:80)
```

The table to write to is created as follows:

```
private static void write(final PCollection<TableRow> data) {
    // Write to BigQuery.
    data.apply(BigQueryIO.writeTableRows()
            .to(new GetPartitionFromTableRowFn("table_name"))
            .withSchema(getOutputSchema())
            .withCreateDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.CreateDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED)
            .withWriteDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.WriteDisposition.WRITE_APPEND));
}

private static TableSchema getOutputSchema() {
    final List<TableFieldSchema> fields = new ArrayList<>();
    fields.add(new TableFieldSchema().setName(ORDER_LINE_REFERENCE).setType("INTEGER"));
    fields.add(new TableFieldSchema().setName(COLUMN_LABEL).setType("STRING"));
    fields.add(new TableFieldSchema().setName(COLUMN_INSERTION_DATETIME).setType("TIMESTAMP"));
    fields.add(new TableFieldSchema().setName(COLUMN_PARTITION_DATE).setType("DATE"));
    return new TableSchema().setFields(fields);
}
```

With the following SerializationFunction:

```
public class GetPartitionFromTableRowFn implements SerializableFunction<ValueInSingleWindow<TableRow>, TableDestination> {
    private final String tableDestination;

    public GetPartitionFromTableRowFn(final String tableDestination) {
        this.tableDestination = tableDestination;
    }

    public TableDestination apply(final ValueInSingleWindow<TableRow> element) {
        final TableDestination tableDestination;
        if (null != element.getValue()) {
            final TimePartitioning timePartitioning = new TimePartitioning().setType("DAY");
            timePartitioning.setField(Constants.COLUMN_PARTITION_DATE);
            final String formattedDate = element.getValue().get(Constants.COLUMN_PARTITION_DATE).toString().replaceAll("-", "");
            // e.g. output$20180801
            final String tableName = String.format("%s$%s", this.tableDestination, formattedDate);
            tableDestination = new TableDestination(tableName, null, timePartitioning);
        } else {
            tableDestination = new TableDestination(this.tableDestination, null);
        }

        return tableDestination;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

1) You are trying to write to a **column partitioned table** described as a partitioned decorator in the table suffix: `some_table_v1$20180811` this is not possible. This syntax works only on **ingestion-time partitioned** tables.

As your table is already partitioned by column according to the error message, this operation is not supported. You need to run an UPDATE or MERGE statements to update a column based partition, and one job is limited to change 1000 partitions only. Or to drop the column based partition and use only ingestion-time partitioned tables.

Note, BigQuery [supports two kind of partitions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/partitioned-tables):

- ingestion time based
- column based.

2) If this is not the case then you need to check again your source tables:

When you copy multiple partitioned tables, note the following:

- If you copy multiple source tables into a partitioned table in the same job, the source tables can't contain a mixture of partitioned and non-partitioned tables.
- If all of the source tables are partitioned tables, the partition specifications for all source tables must match the destination table's partition specification. Your settings determine whether the destination table is appended or overwritten.
  The source and destination tables must be in datasets in the same location.

ps. for further details, please post your tables definition.

3) Look at this solution [BigQuery partitioning with Beam streams](https://medium.com/google-cloud/bigquery-partitioning-with-beam-streams-97ec232a1fcc)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation so far. I'll do some reading on the type of partitioning. Currently, I use a SerializableFunction to determine the table destination. I'll update my question with the code for this.

Comment: @RolfSchellenberger This line of yours confirms you are trying to write to a table that is column partitioned `final TimePartitioning timePartitioning = new TimePartitioning().setType("DAY");` and for the column-partitioned tables table suffix is not supported, as the date partition itself a date column (not a suffix of the table). See solution 3) posted as a link.

Comment: Thanks! So I guess if I remove this TimePartitioning, it will work fine as a ingestion-time partitioned table, since it will use the output$20180801 format?

Comment: probably yes, but you have plenty of information to locate the wrong action

Comment: @Pentium10 Your first point is not true. Partition decorator works for column partitioned tables as well. Check the section of creating partitioned table when loading data or from querying data here: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/creating-column-partitions